# Date range drop down with Jquery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery

I would like to have a drop down menu for quick picking of a date range. So for example, 'Last week', 'Last month', 'Last three months'. That kind of stuff. On picking one of these it will populate 2 text boxes with the from and to dates from the selection. Have tried some stuff with JUI datepicker but after a Google it seems it is not the way to do it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar, but with radio buttons. Hope it helps:

```
    function reset_last_checkboxes() {
        $("#export_last_month").attr("checked", false);
        $("#export_3_last_months").attr("checked", false);
        $("#export_last_year").attr("checked", false);
    }
    var date_format = "DD, d MM, yy";
    $("#id_from_date").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $("#id_till_date").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    $("#id_from_date").datepicker();
    $("#id_till_date").datepicker();
    $( "#id_from_date" ).change(function() {
        $( "#id_from_date" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", date_format );
    });
    $( "#id_till_date" ).change(function() {
        $( "#id_till_date" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", date_format );
    });
    $( "#id_from_date" ).click(function() {
        reset_last_checkboxes();
    });
    $( "#id_till_date" ).click(function() {
        reset_last_checkboxes();
    });
    $("#id_till_date").val(format_date(new Date(now)));
    $("#export_last_month").click(function(){
        var dt = new Date(now);
        $("#id_till_date").val(format_date(dt));
        $("#id_from_date").val(format_date(prevMonth(dt)));
    });
    $("#export_3_last_months").click(function(){
        var dt = new Date(now);
        $("#id_till_date").val(format_date(dt));
        $("#id_from_date").val(format_date(prevMonth(prevMonth(prevMonth(dt)))));
    });
    $("#export_last_year").click(function(){
        var dt = new Date(now);
        $("#id_till_date").val(format_date(dt));
        for (var i=0;i<12;i++) {
            dt = prevMonth(dt);
        }
        $("#id_from_date").val(format_date(dt));
    });
```

You can always replace my radio buttons with drop down menu and write this code better than me :)

By the way, prevMonth I calculate this way:

```
function prevMonth(dt){
    var thisMonth = dt.getMonth();
    dt.setMonth(thisMonth-1);
    if(dt.getMonth() != thisMonth-1 && (dt.getMonth() != 11 || (thisMonth == 11 && dt.getDate() == 1)))
        dt.setDate(0);
    return dt;
}
```